# Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I seem to remember that in PHP there is a way to pass an array as a list of arguments for a function, dereferencing the array into the standard `func($arg1, $arg2)` manner.  But now I'm lost on how to do it.  I recall the manner of passing by reference, how to "glob" incoming parameters ... but not how to de-list the array into a list of arguments.

It may be as simple as `func(&$myArgs)`, but I'm pretty sure that isn't it.  But, sadly, the php.net manual hasn't divulged anything so far.  Not that I've had to use this particular feature for the last year or so.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

**Note: this solution is outdated, please refer to [the answer by simonhamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php#34049110) for newer information.**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
call_user_func_array('func',$myArgs);
```

Comment: Argument unpacking, as it is called, will be added in PHP 5.6 (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking). It will use the 'splat operator': '...'. Its syntax:  
    `$args = [1,2,3];
    function(...$args){}`

Comment: but what if the function you wish to call is an instance method on an object, not a function name in the global space?

Comment: @ahnbizcad then you should use a `callable`, which uses the same `call_user_func_array`, only with array where first element is the object, and second is the method. For example `call_user_func_array([$object, 'method'], $myArgs);`

Comment: This answer is good but out of date. See simonhamp's much simpler solution for modern PHP

Answer (score 199):

[As has been mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php/34049110#comment37967053_744178), as of PHP 5.6+ you can (should!) use the `...` token (aka "splat operator", part of the [variadic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) functionality) to easily call a function with an array of arguments:

```php
function variadic($arg1, $arg2)
{
    // Do stuff
    echo $arg1.' '.$arg2;
}

$array = ['Hello', 'World'];

// 'Splat' the $array in the function call
variadic(...$array);

// => 'Hello World'
```

NB: *Indexed* array items are mapped to arguments by their **position** in the array, not their keys.

**As of PHP8, and [thanks to named arguments](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments), it's possible to use the named keys of an *associative* array with unpacking:**

```php
$array = [
    'arg2' => 'Hello',
    'arg1' => 'World'
];

variadic(...$array);

// => 'World Hello'
```

(Thanks to [mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php/34049110?noredirect=1#comment134333933_34049110) for this note!)

As per [CarlosCarucce's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php/34049110#comment65680057_34049110), this form of argument unpacking **is the fastest method by far** in all cases. In some comparisons, it's over 5x faster than `call_user_func_array`.

### Aside

Because I think this is really useful (though not directly related to the question): you can [type-hint the splat operator parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-151) in your function definition to make sure all of the passed values match a specific type.

(Just remember that doing this it **MUST** be the *last* parameter you define and that it bundles all parameters passed to the function into the array.)

This is great for making sure an array contains items of a specific type:

```php
// Define the function...
function variadic($var, SomeClass ...$items)
{
    // $items will be an array of objects of type `SomeClass`
}

// Then you can call...
variadic('Hello', new SomeClass, new SomeClass);
    
// or even splat both ways
$items = [
    new SomeClass,
    new SomeClass,
];

variadic('Hello', ...$items);
```

Comment: This has a great performance improvement over `call_user_func_array`. So if you're using php 5.6+ I would recommend this one. [Here is a test](https://gist.github.com/nikic/6390366), which was cited in the [official php wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking)

Comment: A relevant side note: named parameters can be unpacked and will respect the key (rather than the element's position). [Does PHP allow named parameters so that optional arguments can be omitted from function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997399/2943403) (see the spread technique at the end of the answer)

Comment: Just in case you missed it like I did since I like to skim fast, the key here is the "..." in front of the array inside the call.

Answer (score 85):

Also note that if you want to apply an instance method to an array, you need to pass the function as:

```
call_user_func_array(array($instance, "MethodName"), $myArgs);
```

Comment: @understack The `$foo->bar()` example on the [linked page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) suggests that it should be `array($instance, "MethodName")`.

Comment: Awesome, I used this to avoid duplicating constructor arguments in a child class :) `call_user_func_array(array(parent, "__construct"), func_get_args());`

Answer (score 11):

For sake of completeness, as of PHP 5.1 this works, too:

```
<?php
function title($title, $name) {
    return sprintf("%s. %s\r\n", $title, $name);
}
$function = new ReflectionFunction('title');
$myArray = array('Dr', 'Phil');
echo $function->invokeArgs($myArray);  // prints "Dr. Phil"
?>
```

See: http://php.net/reflectionfunction.invokeargs

For methods you use [ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs](http://php.net/reflectionmethod.invokeargs) instead and pass the object as first parameter.