# PHP for each argument passed to function

Tags: php

I am passing in anywhere between 1-10 arguments to a function, I would then like the function to run itself for each argument but returning the previous data plus the new data.

So I have a function like follows:

```
function scrape_google_result_source($link,$link2) //$link is "test" $link2 is "test2"
    {
        $html  = $link;
        $cache = $html; //this is my first return

        $html  = $link2;
        $cache = $cache . $html; //this is my first and second return

        return $cache; //now I am returning it so it will be "testtest2"
    }
```

this works if I manually pass in $link1 and $link2 then code it to work with them, I would like it to run itself for each argument passed in then set `$cache .= new result" so I am then returning the result for all the arguments past in together.

Sadly I have no code other than this as I am not to sure where to start with this, I did find the `func_num_args();` php function that could possibly work? Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Is there any reason you don't pass an array of links as parameter ?

Comment: [func_num_args](http://www.php.net/func_num_args) and [func_get_args](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) should work perfectly in this instance if you don't want to pass in/return an array.

Comment: Why not just leave your function with only 1 arg and call it for each link you have.

Comment: Not to sure what the negative vote is for, I know I could well use an array or call it for each argument but I was wondering if this was possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
function scrape_google_result_source($link,$link2)
    {
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        foreach($numargs as $n){
            $link =  func_get_arg($n);
            $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
            $url       = $link;
            $ch        = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
            $html   = curl_exec($ch);
            $cache .= $html; //this is my first return
            curl_close($ch);

        }

        return $cache; //now I am returning it
    }
```

[**func_get_arg manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: This looks like it would do the job, thanks will accept you answer in a few minutes

Comment: I edited the code that was not accumulating the result in `$cache` correctly.

Comment: I already added that into the code provided, thanks again. Its a shame someone down voted without telling me why.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find parsing arrays and looping through easier:

```
function scrape_google_result_source($links)
{

    $cache = '';
    if( !is_array( $links ) )
    {
        return 'not array';
    }
    foreach( $links as $key=>$link )
    {
        $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
        $url       = $link;
        $ch        = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        $html  = curl_exec($ch);
        $cache .= $html;
        curl_close($ch);


    }
    return $cache; //now I am returning it
}


$links_array = array( 'http..','http...');
$html = scrape_google_result_source( $links_array );
```