# In php pass a string as multiple parameters

Tags: php

in PHP i need to use this

```
$pdf->SetXY(56, 100);
```

but now i need the parameters in variables

```
$paramxy= "56, 100";
```

PHP doesn't seem to like me writing

```
$pdf->SetXY($paramxy);
```

it doesn't evaluate "$paramxw" as two separate values..

of course the easy solution would be :

```
$param[x]= 56; 
$param[y]= 100;
$pdf->SetXY($param[x],$param[y]);
```

but i'd like it to be shorter and more readable, because I need lots of these two lines..

is there a "parse" like function that I could use, for example like that ?

```
$pdf_paramxy= "56, 100";
$pdf->SetXY(parse($paramxy));
```

Comment: This smells dangerouly like `eval`...

Answer (score 1):

Native? Not. But you can create your own:

```
$paramxy= "56, 100";
$params = explode(",", $paramxy);
```

Then, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744145/1267304), you can:

```
call_user_func_array(array($pdf, "SetXY"), $params);
```

If values of the array being a string is a problem, you can parse it by each value:

```
foreach($params as $key => $value)
{
    $params[$key] = (int)$value;
}

call_user_func_array(array($pdf, "SetXY"), $params);
```

Didn't tested it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can't set a value for a variable in the following manner `$pdf_nomenfant= "56, 100";`
To achieve your target you have two ways.

1. create two parameters with different values like `$param1 = "56"; and $param2 = "100";`

and the other way is to use an array for this task as in the following:

1. `'$paramxy= array ("56, 100"); $pdf->SetXY(parse($paramxy));`