# Passing an Array as an Argument

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a controller, which calls a different method from a class and I want to make it as generic as possible. I currently have this code:

```
//More code up, just showing the important code part
$geo = new Geolocation();
$res = $geo->{$method}(...$params);

echo json_encode($res);
```

What I want is pass an array as arguments to my Geolocation class.

I took an idea from the next thread: [Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php)

The problem is that "splat operator" `...` is not working for me, probably because it's not a function. Is there any related solution?

PHP 5.6.20

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful statement. Please be more specific.

Comment: Incidentally, works for me https://3v4l.org/i9n28

Comment: @JonStirling:  Guess I should've waited for the answer to _"Not working"_

Comment: @AbraCadaver Just 2 different routes. The answer is relevant and accurate, I'm just more interested in why the splat operator wouldn't be working for OP rather than an explicit solution :D.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was my fault. Any of 2 workarounds are working propertly.

Comment: @JonStirling: Without testing I just assumed it was an issue with the variable method `{$method}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer for the question you link shows `call_user_func_array()`, so with an object method do:

```
$res = call_user_func_array(array($geo, $method), $params);
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, i just overpassed that answer.