# Merge multidimensional array logic

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

## My array

```
$array =

[0] => Array
    (
        [RevPReportPer] => 201606
        [AcctDb] => A
        [AcctNo] => 034
        [AcctBusName] => test
        [AcctDBAName] => test1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [RevPReportPer] => 201606
        [AcctDb] => A
        [AcctNo] => 034
        [AcctBusName] => test2
        [AcctDBAName] => test2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [RevPReportPer] => 201606
        [AcctDb] => A
        [AcctNo] => 036
        [AcctBusName] => COMPUTER
        [AcctDBAName] => computer2
    )
```

## My output

```
[034] => Array
    (
        [RevPReportPer] => Array
            (
                [0] => 201606
                [1] => 201606
            )

        [AcctDb] => Array
            (
                [0] => A
                [1] => A
            )

        [AcctNo] => Array
            (
                [0] => 034
                [1] => 034
            )

        [AcctBusName] => Array
            (
                [0] => test
                [1] => test2
            )

        [AcctDBAName] => Array
            (
                [0] => test1
                [1] => test1
            )

    )

[036] => Array
    (
        [RevPReportPer] => 201606
        [AcctDb] => A
        [AcctNo] => 036
        [AcctBusName] => COMPUTER
        [AcctDBAName] => COMPUTER2

    )
```

I can get the above output using:

```
array_merge_recursive($array[0],$array[1],$array[2]);
```

My question how to pass the values dynamically to `array_merge_recursive()`.

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the array as an array of arguments using `call_user_func_array()`:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AbraCadaver